# How to adjust import order of .css files in Angular

Tags: angular

My current app (generated via Angular CLI) looks like this:

*angular.cli.json (at the root folder):*

```
  ....
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

*src/app/app.module.ts*

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
//angular material
import {MatTabsModule} from "@angular/material";
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
//angular components
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import { CurrentVehicleComponent } from './current-vehicle/current-vehicle.component';
import { BackendCommunicationService } from './backend-communication.service';
import { SharedDataService } from './shared-data.service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CurrentVehicleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    //angular material
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatListModule,
  ],
  providers: [BackendCommunicationService, SharedDataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

If I now serve the app (`ng serve --open`), Angular CLI will include the .css files in the following order:

1. Bootstrap CSS
2. deeppurple-amber.css
3. src/style.css
4. **src/app.component.css**
5. **src/app/current-vehicle.component.css**
6. *.css file from angular material*
7. *another .css file from anular material*

I'm looking for a way, that angular will add my "handwritten" .css files (4., 5. and .css files from not yet implemented components) at the end (i.e. after 6. and 7.).

In detail:

1. Bootstrap CSS
2. deeppurple-amber.css
3. src/style.css
4. *.css file from angular material*
5. *another .css file from anular material*
6. **src/app.component.css**
7. **src/app/current-vehicle.component.css**

How is this possible?

---

#### Update for Bounty

To clarify the issue here. The AngularMaterial components inject their own `<style></style>` tags with the required css for the component you are referencing. This is always added after the `component.css` injected `<style></style>` tags as shown in the first style order listing.

This is an issue because of the following scenario:

```
<a class="my-custom-btn mat-raised-button">Button</a>

.my-custom-btn{margin: 10px;}
.mat-raised-button{margin: 0px;} /* Value From angular material */
```

This is then injected in this order at run time:

```
<style>.my-custom-btn{margin: 10px;}</style>
<style>.mat-raised-button{margin: 0px;}</style>
```

Which means that the only workaround would be `.my-custom-btn{margin: 10px !important}` which is highly unmanigable if you are trying to override some css properties in one component and then a different set of properties in another.

So is there a way to re-arrange the order in which these `<style></style>` tags are injected by angular at run time?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: @Reed Unfortunately not yet. As a workaround I manually override the desired style attributes directly in the component html or in the corresponding component .css file.

Comment: If you do not use encapsulation then I guess it's useless to declare styles in component's folders. You could make a folder with shared styles instead (anyway they are shared). And thus you just have to import them in a right order.

Comment: Have you considered theming angular material. https://material.angular.io/guides This link might give you more idea's to implement your own styles.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to change to,

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css" 
],
```

Then, 
Link all CSS files in styles.css.
Include all files at the top of the styles.css file.

```
@import url('~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('deeppurple-amber.css');
@import url('~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css');
@import url('another_css_file_from_angular_material.css');
@import url('app.component.css'); 
@import url('current-vehicle.component.css');
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: I came here with the same idea for an answer, it should work :)

Comment: I will check this tonight.

Comment: This is the best way of doing it. It also means that you can manage the import order in a single location - which is easy to reason about and maintain  The Angular docs website uses this approach too https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/src/styles/main.scss

Answer (score 3):

Imported CSS will follow the usual 'order of importing' rules, so stylesheets imported later will override earlier ones.

So the first thing to do is make sure that your `last.css` is the last import in index.html

However, components with `styleUrls` use css encapsulation. This means that each component will generate unique class names and specific css rules, which are more specific, that is: `p {color: red}` in a component stylesheet will be remapped to e.g `p[_ngcontent-c1] {color: red}`. This means that if you specify  `p {color: blue}` in your `last.css` it will be less specific than the component one, and won't be applied.

The easiest way to ensure your final rules 'win out' is to set `!important` on them - i.e. `p {color: red !important}` - however this only works if you don't also use `!important` in the component css too!

Alternatively, you can set `encapsulation` to `None` to disable encapsulation and just have global styles:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
// ...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
styles: [
  // ...
]
})
```

However this has to be done for each and every component, and runs the risk of other style rules clashing, so care must be taken with this approach.

Comment: But all the .css files I'm using in the above example will be automatically included via angular CLI. I hoped there are some settings in `angular-cli.json` or somewhere else to adjust the import order

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the import order of CSS works in the following file from Angular.

`angular-cli.json` file has the following config.

```
styles: [style.css ,import 2,...]
```

Base order of the CSS file is mentioned in `angular-cli.json` file.

If you check the `angular-cli.json` file, will have `style.css` as default configured in `styles` array.

imported files inside `.css` will be ordered in a regular manner.

The CSS you have written in the component level will be loaded with the component on execution.

Hope this helps you.